# Cant start Windows Firewall from control panel

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I have a weird problem. 
I try to open the Windows Firewall settings through the control panel.
What i do, basically , is to click on Control Panel > System and Maintenance > Windows Firewall.
Well nothing happens. No error message no nothing. Just nothing opens.
The service runs as it should.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: given you had no luck with restore.. there may be a regsvr command of sorts to uninstall and install it. But, consider if xp, a repair installation. if windows 7 it may be called an upgrade installation and need to be done from within windows though i haven't tried it.

Comment: an SFC /SCANNOW might be worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

try using start > run > firewall.cpl

Try restoring system to a fine restoration point, or copy %windir%\System32\firewall.cpl from a fine windows installation to replace yours.
This issue may be caused by data corruption in firewall.cpl.

Comment: Tried that. Nothing happened

Comment: @Pantheo Running that command opens the firewall so you probably have some corrupt files - have you tried the second suggestion?

Comment: @easwee I run sfc /scannow. The process did not find anything wrong with my Windows files. Still cant open the firewall. The strange thing is that if i disable the firewall i can open the firewall settings through the control panel.